# String Comparison Issue (C++)

Tags: c++, c-strings

**Problem Solved: StringVariable[position] (in this case Word[e]) outputs a value that is defined as a char variable type rather than the string variable type I had expected it to. Thank you all for your help!**

When I run my Hangman game I get the following error:

> Error  2   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> Error  1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> 4   IntelliSense: no operator "!=" matches these operands
>
> 3   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands

I commented in the code where this error points to and copied in the functions related to the problem. The functions were then run in the main() function to simplify the code.

This section of the code is meant to check if the guess is equal to the letter in the word. Let me know if I need to provide further explanation.

Related Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Functions
void GrabWord();
void DiscoverLet();
void guess();

//Variables
int NumL, Fl, F, count[10];
string G, Word;

//Grab Word from .txt and define NumL
void GrabWord()
{
    //Grab Random Line from .txt
    //Random Line >> Larray
    Word = "short";
    NumL = Word.size();
}

//Checks if Guess matches any letters
void DiscoverLet()
{
    for(int e = 0; e < NumL; e++)
    {
        //Error Points to the following two comparisons
        if(G == Word[e])
        {
            count[e] = 1;
        }
        else if(G != Word[e])
        {
            Fl++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: DiscoverLet(), G to Word[]\n";
        }
    }
    if(Fl == NumL)
    {
        F = F + 1;
    }
    Fl = 0;
}
```

Comment: What `G` is supposed to be?

Comment: Can't you present a [mcve]?

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot G is a letter that the user inputs

Answer (score 2):

The proper string comparison that you are looking for is called [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

```
if(Word.find(G) > std::string::npos)
{
    count[e] = 1;
}
else
{
    Fl++;
}
```

The reason why your comparison does not work was that you Word[e] was grabbing a `character` of the string and it was being compared to a `string` variable.

Judging by your code it looks like you wanted to count the number of times the letter appears in the string. If you wanted to count the number of times the letter appears in the string then you can use the find function like this:

```
int count = 0;
int foundIdx = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < NumL; i++)
{
    foundIdx = Word.find(G, foundIdx+1);

    if (foundIdx == std::string::npos)
    {
        break;
    }

    count++;
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::string::npos` instead of -1.  The function says it returns `string::npos` if the find is not successful.  There is nothing in the standard that says `std::string::npos` will have the value of -1.

Comment: It says on [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) that it's equal to -1. But you're right, I'll change it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- actually (and unfortunately), the standard does say that `std::string::npos` is -1. That was not in the original version of the string class (I was one of the co-authors), and it sneaked in later, while I wasn't looking. Nevertheless, your point is right: use `std::string::npos` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(G == Word[e])
...
    else if(G != Word[e])
```

In these comparisons, `G` is a `string` and `Word[e]` is a character in a `string`.  There is no operator to perform the respective comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

G is a variable of type string. Word is also a type of string. So as you might already know that strings are nothing but array of chars. So Word[e] points to a character of the Word string. So

```
if(G == Word[e])
```

Here, you are comparing a string with a character. But C++ has no idea how to do that! I mean C++ does not know how to evaluate the expression. Because the operator == for comparing a string and a char is not overloaded inside string class. Same goes for the line

```
if(G != Word[e])
```

If you're trying to find out if Word[e] character appears in the G string, you should run another loop searching character by character of the string G. Or you can use find function.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I didn't realize that pointing to the spot in the string array changed it to a char.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is because you are comparing string to a character. You can use ==, !=, >, <, etc on character, but certainly not strings. And also, the string G appears to be empty. Hope this helps and correct me if I'm wrong! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`G` is `string` type but `Word[e]` is `char` type. You should convert `Word[e]` to `String` to compare with `G` by `std::to_string` or use method `string::find` with `G` to find content `Word[e]` in `G`.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison won't work that way. You need to understand what is the difference between a `char` and a `std::string`. A variable of type `char` represent a single letter. A `char` cannot be multiple character, and cannot be empty. Is strictly one, single letter. Nothing less, nothing more.

A `std::string` can be seen as a managed array of `char`. It's size can be 0 to very big. This type expose the array access operator, the `[n]`, and that operator returns a character from the string at position `n`. It's return type is `char`.

Since `G` is supposed to be an input letter from the user, I'd suggest you to declare `G` as a `char`. In fact, it will solve your problem.

The reason for that a string cannot be compared to a single character. A string is designed to be comparable to another whole string. And a character can be compared with another integral, or put it simpler, another char. So if you change the type of `G` to `char`, your comparison will work as expected.